# What causes google fonts' styles to not work by adding the style name after the font family?

Tags: css, fonts

For example, if I use this format in using **Black** style for **Montserrat** font it does not work:

```
font-family: 'Montserrat-Black';
```

Instead, I have to use:

```
font-family: 'Montserrat';
font-weight: 900;
```

What is exactly the reason for being unable to use the style by its name in font family?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the system only knows the font-family "Montserrat". The system doesn't know about font-family "Montserrat-Black", but it knows it has to load the font "Montserrat-Black" when the user calls for the font-family "Montserrat" with "font-weight: 900".

```
<style>

@font-face {
  font-family: "Montserrat-Black";
  src: local(Montserrat-Black);
}

</style>

<div style="font-family: 'Montserrat-Black'">Test</div>
<div style="font-family: 'Montserrat'">Test</div>
```

You can work around this using font-face.